# How to recompile a '.h file' on mac?

Tags: c

I am using a tool that has been written in C or C++.

https://github.com/kern-lab/discoal

I've never used C myself. In one of the files in discoal.h, I want to change: `#define MAXSITES 220020` to `#define MAXSITES 1100000`. The tool manual says that I would have change the MAXSITES define in discoal.h and then recompile.  How do I recompile?

I have never used C language before and I am not a Computer science student therefore, do not have much experience in programming either. Therefore, if you could let me know the command to recompile that'll be great. I've provided a link to that tool in case you want to look at the files.

Comment: Just run `make`

Comment: You mean make discoal.h?

Comment: No @ShafaHaider, just `make`, see my answer.

Comment: .h files are header containing definitions and declarations. What must be recompiled is the complete set of .c files of the program. The way to do that is system dependent, but if there is a Makefile in you directory, you can just type make.

Comment: First you have to install a C compiler, which on a Mac means installing Xcode.

Comment: You normally don't compile `.h` files. `.h` files are included, directly or indirectly, by `.c` files (using a `#include` directive that tells the compiler to copy the contents of the named file at that point). If you modify a `.h` file, you'll need to recompile all the `.c` files that directly or indirectly depend on it. It's the job of the `make` tool to figure that out and do it for you (directed by a `Makefile` that specifies what depends on what).

Comment: Thank you Keith Thompson. It clarifies a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal, cd to the directory where the Makefile is, and type `make`, then hit Enter.

Prerequisites: A C compiler, which comes with Xcode on a Mac, as @Shawn commented.